# MySQL select a certain amout of rows for each type in a certain c

Tags: mysql, sql, database, navicat

I would like to select the first certain number of rows, by groups of a certain column. For example :

Original data:

```
  index   type     value
0       1    a  0.716430
1       2    a  0.223650
2       3    a  0.375417
3       4    a  0.773874
4       5    a  0.802127
5       6    a  0.956563
6       7    b  0.377718
7       8    b  0.487772
8       9    b  0.672767
9      10    b  0.275895
10     11    b  0.981751
11     12    b  0.914780
12     13    b  0.940582
13     14    c  0.347563
14     15    c  0.101106
15     16    c  0.390205
16     17    c  0.235941
17     18    c  0.593234
18     19    c  0.904659
```

I would like to select the first 4 rows for each unique value of `type`, and the order is by `index`.

So the ideal result would be:

```
      index    type    value
0       1.0      a  0.716430
1       2.0      a  0.223650
2       3.0      a  0.375417
3       4.0      a  0.773874
4       7.0      b  0.377718
5       8.0      b  0.487772
6       9.0      b  0.672767
7      10.0      b  0.275895
8      14.0      c  0.347563
9      15.0      c  0.101106
10     16.0      c  0.390205
11     17.0      c  0.235941
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`row_number()` is the typical solution to this:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by type order by index) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 4;
```

In older versions of MySQL, you can do:

```
select tm.*
from telegram_message tm
where tm.index <= coalesce( (select tm2.index
                             from telegram_message tm2
                             where tm2.type = tm.type
                             order by tm2.index asc
                             limit 1 offset 3
                            ), tm.index
                          );
```

The `coalesce()` is so all rows are taken if there are not 4 rows for the type.

Comment: Thanks! But error occured：`[SQL]select telegram_message.*
from (select telegram_message.*,
             row_number() over (partition by coin order by date) as seqnum
      from telegram_message
     ) telegram_message
where seqnum <= 1000;
[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by coin order by date) as seqnum
      from telegram_message
     )' at line 3`

Answer (score 1):

You can get the result you want by self joining your table on `index`, where the value of `index` in the joined table is less than that in the first, and selecting only those rows which have < 4 rows with lower index values:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.index, t1.type, t1.value
FROM test t1
LEFT JOIN test t2 ON t2.index < t1.index AND t2.type = t1.type
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.index, t1.type, t1.value
HAVING COUNT(t2.index) < 4
```

Output:

```
id  index   type    value
0   1       a       0.71643
1   2       a       0.22365
2   3       a       0.375417
3   4       a       0.773874
6   7       b       0.377718
7   8       b       0.487772
8   9       b       0.672767
9   10      b       0.275895
13  14      c       0.347563
14  15      c       0.101106
15  16      c       0.390205
16  17      c       0.235941
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7oepx87s8yL3Kz7z53gcVk/0)